# Progress bar while formatting removable drives is inacruate

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, formatting, progress

Why is the progress bar in windows operating systems not really displaying the progress of the format.

It is only displaying when the format is already completed. What I'm trying to say is, you cannot really see that the progress bar is moving until the format is completed, and is inaccurate while at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty standard windows functionality, the progress bars are never accurate.  Normally a USB drive will be formatted so fast that the progress bar is a bit pointless.